# Including a JS library in the root view can't be used by partial view using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When I include a JS library in my partial view, subsequent button clicks don't have access to the included library.

If I include the library in the root view, any reference to the library in the partial views fails.

I have been having a lot of trouble using a JavaScript library in my htmlPartial view. I have a partial view that uses the JSTree library, which looks something like this:

```html
@model modelData

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.12/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="my-tree">
</div>

<button onclick="clickButton()"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function renderTree() {

    $('#my-tree').jstree({
      "core": {
        "data": data,
        "themes": {
          "dots": false,
          "icons": false
        }
      },
      "checkbox": {
        "three_state": false,
        "keep_selected_style": true
      },
      "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"]
    });
  }

  function clickButton() {

    console.log($("#my-tree").jstree("get_selected").text());
  }
</script>
```

When I run it the tree renders fine, but when I click the button (to get the selected nodes) it fails with the error:

> TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function

The fix, I have found to this, is to include the jstree.min.js include in the root view as well as the partial.

Here's a breakdown of what I have tried:

1. include in the partial view only (fail)
2. include in the root view only (fail)
3. include in both (works)

[image]

So my question is, why does this behavior happen? Here was my thinking:

1. The button was in the same scope as the library include, so it
   should have access to it
2. The library was included in the root so all
   views should have access to it

EDIT

Here is the root cshtml file

```html
@section Scripts {
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.12/jstree.min.js"></script>
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css">


<div class="tree">
  <div>
    @(await Html.PartialAsync("MyPartialModule", Model))
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us please the .NET Code? It might be because of wrong referencing

Comment: @SamySammour I have editted the question, ta

Comment: bear in mind, the root section is whats working, I didnt have the includes at first